# which words is the best choice here? (What I mean by that is / I mean ) / the way (that / in which) /

Tags: sentence-construction

> Q: Do you prefer to listen to other's opinions or to make a decision on your own?
>
> A: I feel I have to say that I'm a person who doesn't listen to other's opinions. ***(What I mean by that is / I mean )*** I have live in the way ***(that / in which)*** I think I should not others think I should in my whole life, which I think is not always good. I think I need to fix ***(this side / this feature / this characteristic)*** of me.

1. Here, I'm perfectly comfortable using ***I mean***, but I'd like to know if the other one is also possible here.
2. And I'm more comfortable using ***that***, but at the same time I feel ***in which*** is better grammatically. what would you choose?
3. I think all of these are possible but I feel ***side*** is better than the other. What do you think is most natural?

Comment: "I mean" is better and brief, "that" sounds better, "this side" is also good! But it is "have lived", after "should not" you should use a verb "I should not others think" is not sensible

Comment: You just need a semicolon to make it understandable: "..the way I think I should; not how others think I should, my whole life."

Answer (score 0):

I reccomend that you never, under any circumstance, use the phrase "***What I mean by that is***"

Consider the following example:

> 1. ***What I mean by that is***, I want to start recycling.
> 2. I want to start recycling.

That being said, I have re-written your original text in order to improve grammatical correctness and readability:

> I have to say that I am a person who doesn't listen to other's opinions. I have lived my whole life in the way that I think I should; not as others think that I should. I think that this is not always good. I think that I need to work on this characteristic of myself.